# smbd crashes after logout or failed login attempt

Tags: samba

I'm running smbd 3.6.7 on Arch. It works fine, except that it crashes when on failed login attempts and after logoff.

Here is an example using the wrong password. `rpcclient` is run in one terminal, and `smbd` in the other. The `smbd` process ends when `rpcclient` sends the wrong password.

```
$ rpcclient -L localhost -Utim
Enter tim's password: 
Cannot connect to server.  Error was NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
$
```

//

```
$ sudo smbd -i -d 2
smbd version 3.6.7 started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 egid=0
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Registered MSG_REQ_POOL_USAGE
Registered MSG_REQ_DMALLOC_MARK and LOG_CHANGED
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[homes]"
Processing section "[media]"
Processing section "[karin-backup]"
added interface eth0 ip=fe80::226:2dff:fe78:ac61%eth0 bcast=fe80::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff%eth0 netmask=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
added interface eth0 ip=192.168.1.5 bcast=192.168.1.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
waiting for connections
check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [tim] -> [tim] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
$
```

Example with the right password:

```
$ rpcclient -L localhost -Utim
Enter tim's password: 
rpcclient $> getusername
Account Name: tim, Authority Name: JANA
rpcclient $> quit
$
```

//

```
$ sudo smbd -i -d 2
smbd version 3.6.7 started.
...
waiting for connections
check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [tim] -> [tim] -> [tim] succeeded
$
```

It also crashes if I try to connect to a share from Windows (XP) with the wrong password. With the right password, I *can* access the share.

What could the problem be?

Here is my smb.conf: http://pastebin.com/sGyu2XWh